# while using split() in python, the names are printed as a single string?

Tags: python, split

```
names_string = input("Give me everybody's names, separated by a comma. ")
names = names_string.split(", ")
print(names)
```

Comment: `names = names_string.split(", ")` creates a list of strings, which you print with `print(names)` - what exactly is the problem?

Comment: it is printed as a single list ['amal,achu,arun'] like this

Comment: you want split(",") and not split(", ")

Comment: Would you like to print names one by row? Please specify input/output cases next time :)
Try to use \n separator
```print("\n".join(names))```

Comment: did not put space after comma. That was the error.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. If you want to print names as new lines, here's how:

```
names_string = input("Give me everybody's names, separated by a comma. ") 
names = names_string.split(", ") 
for i in names:
    print(i)
```

Comment: You could also do `print(*names, sep='\n')`. The `*` will unpack the list (essentially get all its values into the print function) and `sep` is a kwarg you can pass to the print function to define what character you want to use to separate the given args. Default is `sep=" "`.

Comment: @Mathias Sven I'd say more important advice would've been to read the comments under the question and actually fix the OP's mistake.

Comment: @KellyBundy I don't see how tiykuma don't answer the OP's question. How they were inputting the names in (with the extra space or not) seemed lateral as they would still get a list printed on a single line

Comment: @Mathias Sven Single line, yes, but not single string (which is what the question complains about). Also, this answer *still* prints all in a single line (unless the split argument is changed or the input is changed, neither of which the answer does or talks about).

Comment: [Yes it does](https://tio.run/##Tc0xCsMwEETR3qcY3MQG4SZNCKTOMcLa3sQLlrRIskGnV4TSZOrHH81p8@5601CKI8vxFVMQ98ED4vRIQ/@Uk2EZfHLIs1/zJaJJg8hKgRKvmDMIi7eWJvQjugZq4z85Rd2lBk0Tbx8g9eNH7h3qtLI0yFgKWdoNLdthKBzuCw). Why did you claim it doesn't? We're you hoping I'm not able to test it?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).